# AVSpeechSynthesizer.speak crashes when AVSpeechUtterance uses Alex and an attributed string

Tags: ios, swift

Updated after more testing to narrow the issue down (thanks OOPer).

My app uses text to speech, I'm using `AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString:` so I can use `AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute` to specify pronunciations of specific words.

The app crashes on device if Alex is set.

To reproduce:

1) Download Alex (Settings/General/Accessibility/Speech/Voices/English/Alex) - note 869Mb!

2) Run the following

```
    let anyString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Any string")
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString: anyString)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(identifier: AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceIdentifierAlex)
    AVSpeechSynthesizer().speak(utterance)
```

The error is:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'"

Notes:

The Apple documentation say's that Alex is only available in the US, and I'm using a UK device BUT:

1) You CAN download Alex in the UK, and if you do it will be returned by `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()`. If you enumerate the list and select it (by, for example, saying you want the first English Enhanced voice, as I did) then the app will crash.

2) The crash happens even if you set your locale to US and set Alex as your default voice.

3) My issue is that my app is global but English speaking (if that makes sense) so I need to select a specific "En" language from those available on device, at the moment I'm having to work round by excluding Alex.

4) Tested on IOS 12.0 (iPad) and 12.0.1 (6s) (both crash), I don't have any devices with earlier IOS versions.

My questions:

1) Can anyone in the US do me the favour of seeing if this crash happens on a genuine US device?

2) Can anyone think of a fix/workaround that doesn't exclude Alex? After all, the user might have selected it as their preferred voice...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same issue with my iPhone 7+. Does your issue happen only on the specific devices? Or depends on some other conditions like iOS version?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt OOPer, it seems to be device specific (I've now tested on a 6s, SE, iPad Air 2 & iPad Pro 9.7, it only crashes on the 6s). All have IOS 12.0.1, must be something I've done to my 'phone.

Comment: Even if you have done something to your 6s, your code should work and you may need some workarounds (or the right way). Better edit your question and include as much known fact as you can. Someone may find it and give you a useful suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, advice much appreciated. I'm still investigating, there seems to be a link with using enhanced voices (Alex in this case), but I want to be more definitive before I re-phrase the question.

Comment: NOTE: QUESTION UPDATED AS SUGGESTED BY OOPer